# Angular: Async pipe subscribes to late

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, observable, kendo-ui-angular2

My problem: I have a reactive form, that is opend as a new window with the KendoUI WindowManager.

```js
  public openEditWindow(item: Item): void {
    const window: WindowRef = this.windowService.open({
      title: 'Update Item',
      content: NewComponent,
      top: 12,
      left: 198,
      width: 1259,
      height: 800
    });
    window.content.instance.fillForm(item);

  }
```

I load data into this form via `window.content.instance.fillForm(item);`
The class looks somewhat like this:

```js
formgroup: FormGroup
public ProblemChild: Observable<string>;
constructor(formBuilder: formbuilder) {

this.formGroup = formbuilder.group({
name: ['', required]
something: ['']
})

this.problemChild = combineLatest([this.formGroup.controls.name.valueChanges, this.formGroup.controls.something.valuechanges]).pipe(map(/*Do Stuff*/))
}

public fillForm(item: Item): void{
this.formgroup.controls.name.setValue(item.name)
...

}
```

The HTML looks like this

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup"> 
...
</form>
{{problemChild | async}}
```

the `fillForm` function is called between the ctor and the OnInit function.
In other words: I got all my data before the component is rendered, and my `problemChild` wont display the computed data until the all relevant fields are updated again by the user.

If this is not quite understandable, I did a small mock with the same behavior
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fqyhwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
here the Subjects are stand-ins for the `valueChanges` und the Update button is the stand-in for the input fields

As far as my understanding of angular goes, the async pipe subscribes to the `problemChild` observable once the component is rendered and starting at this moment, the `combineLatest` will actually start listening to the `valueChanges`.
Which brought me to the idea, to save the item in a variable and just set the values in the ngAfterViewInit. Which also did not work since it causes the input fields (kendoTextbox) to look like there is no value in them (Label is IN the field) but the field is populated, causing the label and the valuetext to overlap. You have to click the field once to for it to work properly again. So this is not an option.

What I now did was to `shareReplay()` the combineLatest and to subscripe to it instantly.
All data will be displayed correct but now I got a random subscription that doesnt do anything.
Is there a better way?

Comment: can't you call the form's `setValue` with `setTimeout` to trigger the observable?

Comment: I could, but this would be as much of an unclean solution as the one I currently have, IMO